# Get list mapped over featureCollection for multiple regions

Tags: google-earth-engine, list, google-earth-engine-python-api, feature-collection, lambda

I am attempting to convert my normal GEE GUI JavaScript code over to Python using a Colab environment. In JavaScript I had successfully been able to display and use in calculations multiple regions (in this example region_id's 1960, 1961, and 1955) the  in an admin shapefile using this code:

```
var multiStateList = [1960,1961,1955]; 
var filterMulti = function(ids){
  return ee.FeatureCollection(ids.map(function(x){
  return state.filterMetadata('region_id', 'equals', x)})).flatten();
};
var state1 = filterMulti(multiStateList);
Map.addLayer(state1,{},'Multi-State',false);
```

Where `state` was the admin shapefile. I have attempted to recreate it in Colab (I am also new to python and am not great with any programming language in all honesty) and this is what I pieced together:

```
multiStateList = [1960,1961,1955]
def filterMulti(ids):
  return ee.FeatureCollection(ids.map(lambda x: state.filterMetadata('region_id', 'equals', x))).flatten()

multiReg = filterMulti(multiStateList)
my_map.add_ee_layer(multiReg,{},'Multiple Regions')

my_map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
display(my_map)
```

The error that I keep getting is `'list' object has no attribute 'map'`.

Is there something minor that I am missing or do I need a major rewrite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to perform a GEE server-side operation on a Python list object, which is not possible.

Try making an [ee.List](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-list) from it first:

```
multiStateList = ee.List([1960,1961,1955])
```